# How i set path of xampp from C to D drive

Tags: php, configuration, xampp, localhost, server

i have installed XAMPP server on my system D drive.But issue is that
when i open local host its working but i have created a folder in the
`(D:/Xampp/htdocs/myfolder)`.In this folder i have created a file that
is index.HTML.When i try to access this file from URL `(local
host/my-folder)`. its showing **Object not found**. I think its D
drive issue.how i set the path for D drive for my local network.

```
**Object not found!**
```

Comment: Have you configured your httpd.conf to point to the correct directory for htdocs?

Comment: yes i have tried 

DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs"

<Directory ""D:/xampp/htdocs">

Answer (score 2):

Try the folder name correctly.

Like `localhost/myfolder`

this is correct format to run the url.

Answer (score 0):

Try with your apache port number like the given below example

localhost:80/my-folder